# multiple sliders in one page website with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have to multiple sliders in my website. this code not work in my page for 3 sliders in one page.
but worked in one slider in one page. please help me do I it?
I need that this sliders worked in one page in my website. This sliders have to work into the accordion hover in one page.
The problem is that when I put all the slides, they all come together in one accordion.
In general, the main problem is that three sliders on one page do not work with this code

```js
const slider = function () {
    // const this_slider = this;
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    const btnLeft = document.querySelector('.slider__btn--left');
    const btnRight = document.querySelector('.slider__btn--right');
    const dotContainer = document.querySelector('.dots');
  
    let curSlide = 0;
    const maxSlide = slides.length;
  
    // Functions
    const createDots = function () {
            slides.forEach(function (_, i) {
            dotContainer.insertAdjacentHTML(
            'beforeend',
            `<button class="dots__dot" data-slide="${i}"></button>`
            );
        });
    };
  
    const activateDot = function (slide) {
        document
            .querySelectorAll('.dots__dot')
            .forEach(dot => dot.classList.remove('dots__dot--active'));
    
        document
            .querySelector(`.dots__dot[data-slide="${slide}"]`)
            .classList.add('dots__dot--active');
    };
  
    const goToSlide = function (slide) {
        slides.forEach(
            (s, i) => (s.style.transform = `translateX(${100 * (i - slide)}%)`)
        );
    };
  
    // Next slide
    const nextSlide = function () {
        if (curSlide === maxSlide - 1) {
            curSlide = 0;
        } else {
            curSlide++;
        }
    
        goToSlide(curSlide);
        activateDot(curSlide);
    };
  
    const prevSlide = function () {
        if (curSlide === 0) {
            curSlide = maxSlide - 1;
        } else {
            curSlide--;
        }
        goToSlide(curSlide);
        activateDot(curSlide);
    };
  
    const init = function () {
        goToSlide(0);
        createDots();
    
        activateDot(0);
    };
    init();
  
    // Event handlers
    btnRight.addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
    btnLeft.addEventListener('click', prevSlide);
  
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') prevSlide();
        e.key === 'ArrowRight' && nextSlide();
    });
  
    dotContainer.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('dots__dot')) {
            const { slide } = e.target.dataset;
            goToSlide(slide);
            activateDot(slide);
        }
    });
};
slider();
```

```css
/* SLIDER */
.slider {
  max-width: 100rem;
  height: 50rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;

  /* IN THE END */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50rem;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  /* THIS creates the animation! */
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.slide > img {
  /* Only for images that have different size than slide */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slider__btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;

  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  /* background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); */
  font-family: inherit;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 5.5rem;
  width: 5.5rem;
  font-size: 3.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider__btn--left {
  left: 6%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.slider__btn--right {
  right: 6%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}

.dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
}

.dots__dot {
  border: none;
  background-color: #b9b9b9;
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1.75rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s;

  /* Only necessary when overlying images */
  /* box-shadow: 0 0.6rem 1.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); */
}

.dots__dot:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.dots__dot--active {
  /* background-color: #fff; */
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 1;
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a grey background color */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
                        <div class="slide">
                            <img src="img/img-1.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                
                        <div class="slide">
                            <img src="img/img-2.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                
                        <div class="slide">
                            <img src="img/img-3.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                
                        <div class="slide">
                            <img src="img/img-4.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                
                        <button class="slider__btn slider__btn--left">&#10094;</button>
                        <button class="slider__btn slider__btn--right">&#10095;</button>
                        <div class="dots"></div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: The slider function doesn't seem to take account of just one slider, it's looking at all the slides on the page not at the slides in that slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your html, css and script for demo.
html - added two more sliders and separated them.
css  - added button colors for visibility
javascript - you can see it.

```js
// We have to declare the function for all the sliders 

// get all slider from document.
const slideContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');

// lets put your function to every one of them
for(let i = 0; i < slideContainer.length; i++){

    const slider = function () {
        // const this_slider = this;
        const slides = slideContainer[i].querySelectorAll('.slide');  // Your code was : const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');  don't search the entire document, only search the slider
        const btnLeft = slideContainer[i].querySelector('.slider__btn--left');
        const btnRight = slideContainer[i].querySelector('.slider__btn--right');
        const dotContainer = slideContainer[i].querySelector('.dots');
      
        let curSlide = 0;
        const maxSlide = slides.length;
      
        // Functions
        const createDots = function () {
                slides.forEach(function (_, i) {
                dotContainer.insertAdjacentHTML(
                'beforeend',
                `<button class="dots__dot" data-slide="${i}"></button>`
                );
            });
        };
      
        const activateDot = function (slide) {
            slideContainer[i]
                .querySelectorAll('.dots__dot')
                .forEach(dot => dot.classList.remove('dots__dot--active'));
        
            slideContainer[i]
                .querySelector(`.dots__dot[data-slide="${slide}"]`)
                .classList.add('dots__dot--active');
        };
      
        const goToSlide = function (slide) {
            slides.forEach(
                (s, i) => (s.style.transform = `translateX(${100 * (i - slide)}%)`)
            );
        };
      
        // Next slide
        const nextSlide = function () {
            if (curSlide === maxSlide - 1) {
                curSlide = 0;
            } else {
                curSlide++;
            }
        
            goToSlide(curSlide);
            activateDot(curSlide);
        };
      
        const prevSlide = function () {
            if (curSlide === 0) {
                curSlide = maxSlide - 1;
            } else {
                curSlide--;
            }
            goToSlide(curSlide);
            activateDot(curSlide);
        };
      
        const init = function () {
            goToSlide(0);
            createDots();
        
            activateDot(0);
        };
        init();
      
        // Event handlers
        btnRight.addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
        btnLeft.addEventListener('click', prevSlide);
      
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') prevSlide();
            e.key === 'ArrowRight' && nextSlide();
        });
      
        dotContainer.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            if (e.target.classList.contains('dots__dot')) {
                const { slide } = e.target.dataset;
                goToSlide(slide);
                activateDot(slide);
            }
        });
    };
    slider();
}
```

```css
/* SLIDER */
.slider {
    max-width: 100rem;
    height: 50rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
  
    /* IN THE END */
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .slide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50rem;
  
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  
    /* THIS creates the animation! */
    transition: transform 1s;
  }
  
  .slide > img {
    /* Only for images that have different size than slide */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
  .slider__btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
  
    border: none;
    background-color: black;                // your was "inherit" . changed this for my visibility. 
    /* background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); */
    font-family: inherit;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 5.5rem;
    width: 5.5rem;
    font-size: 3.25rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .slider__btn--left {
    left: 6%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .slider__btn--right {
    right: 6%;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .dots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .dots__dot {
    border: none;
    background-color: #b9b9b9;
    opacity: 0.7;
    height: 1rem;
    width: 1rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 1.75rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s;
  
    /* Only necessary when overlying images */
    /* box-shadow: 0 0.6rem 1.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); */
  }
  
  .dots__dot:last-child {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .dots__dot--active {
    /* background-color: #fff; */
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .slideshow-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
  }
  
  /* Next & previous buttons */
  .prev,
  .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -22px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  /* Position the "next button" to the right */
  .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  }
  
  /* On hover, add a grey background color */
  .prev:hover,
  .next:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/img-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/img-2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/img-3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/img-4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <button class="slider__btn slider__btn--left">&#10094;</button>
        <button class="slider__btn slider__btn--right">&#10095;</button>
        <div class="dots"></div>
    </div>

    <hr> <!-- This to separate the slider (optional)-->

    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/img-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/img-2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/img-3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/img-4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <button class="slider__btn slider__btn--left">&#10094;</button>
        <button class="slider__btn slider__btn--right">&#10095;</button>
        <div class="dots"></div>
    </div>

    <hr> <!-- This to separate the slider (optional)-->

    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/img-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/img-2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/img-3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/img-4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>

        <button class="slider__btn slider__btn--left">&#10094;</button>
        <button class="slider__btn slider__btn--right">&#10095;</button>
        <div class="dots"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: very very very Thank you